# Why my swagger is not working in java with springboot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, web-services

**Please suggest how to solve this problem.I am stuck here.**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);

    }
}
```

*Error message is following;*

- *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START

  ---

  Description:

  Parameter 0 of method linkDiscoverers in
  org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration required a
  single bean, but 17 were found:

  - modelBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - typeNameProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - syntheticModelProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - documentationPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - operationBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - parameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry: defined in null
  - operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - defaultsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - pathDecoratorRegistry: defined in null
  - apiListingScannerPluginRegistry: defined in null
  - relProviderPluginRegistry: defined by method 'relProviderPluginRegistry' in class path resource
    [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]
  - linkDiscovererRegistry: defined in null
  - entityLinksPluginRegistry: defined by method 'entityLinksPluginRegistry' in class path resource
    [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcEntityLinksConfiguration.class]

  Action:

  Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
  to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
  that should be consumed

Answer (score 3):

You can change your configuration class by adding the following bean

```
@Bean
public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
    List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
    plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
    return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
}
```

the configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
    }

    @Bean
    public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
        List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
        return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot resolve 'LinkDiscoverers' is show. how too handle it ?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you're using Swagger 2.9.2 and SpringBoot 2.2.x. It has an [open issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932) with compatibility.

Comment: yes i am using 2.9.2 version and i guess my springboot is 2.2 or above.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below configuration class to fix this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("package Name")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket siteOfficeApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .select()
               .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                    .basePackage("Basepackage"))
               .paths(PathSelectors.any())
               .build()
               .apiInfo(metaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
            "Title",
            "Description",
            "Version",
            "Terms of service",
            "Contact Name",
            "License",
            "Licence URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

With these two maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you added following dependencies to your pom.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>**[version here]**</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>**[version here]**</version>
    </dependency>
```

If it doesn't work please provide more info.

Comment: It didnot work.i am using springboot 2.2.0 and swagger versio 2.9.2 on both swagger dependencies.

Comment: I'm using older versions and they're working fine for me... as others said there might be compatibility issues.. so you could either switch to other version or wait...

Answer (score 0):

I made the BootApplication as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BootApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements 
WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

@Bean
public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
    List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
    plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
    return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
}

@Bean
public BootApplicationProperties bootApplicationProperties() {
    return new BootApplicationProperties();
}

/**
 * main for running the app.
 *
 * @param args main arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

then negate the profile for test to avoid fail during testing and set the swagger configuration as below.

```
    @Profile({"local","dev", "deva","devb","devc","staging","prod", "!test"})
    @EnableSwagger2
    @Configuration
    public class SwaggerConfig /*extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport*/ {

        public Docket productApi() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.wellsfargo.fcp.uae.goaml.controller"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build();
        }

       /* @Bean
        public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
            List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
            plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
            return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
        }*/



        private ApiInfo metaData() {
            /*ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder("Spring Boot REST API", "Spring Boot REST API for Online Store", "1.0",
                    "Terms of service", new Contact("Hatice Sigirci", null, "hatice.sigirci@hotmail.com"),
                    "Apache License Version 2.0", "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0", null);
            return apiInfo;*/
            return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Boot REST API")
                    .description("Boot REST API reference ")
                    .termsOfServiceUrl("http://tchelpcom")
                    .contact("http://tchelp com").license("©  All rights reserved")
                    .licenseUrl("http://tchelp.com").version("1.0").build();
        }

    }
```